How can I test if a Blazor Component string is rendered as a MarkupString in bUnit?
I have a simple Blazor Component that renders a string and a test that checks the html content is rendered when the component is rendered.
However - if I change the line with the markup string  @(new MarkupString(TextContent)) to use use the raw string @TextContent then the test still passes, even though when I look at the output in the running application the html foramtting is not applied (as you'd expect, the raw html is shown on the page rather than the stlyed content). Even though it displays differently to the user, the bUnit test gets the exact same string back in both cases.
So how can I modify this test so that the raw output fails the test while the MarkupString version still passes?
<div class="text-content">
    @if (!string.IsNullEmptyOrWhitespace(TextContent))
    {
        @(new MarkupString(TextContent)) 
    }
</div>


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string TextContent { get; set; } = "";   
}



[Test]
[TestCase("<h1>Content Here</h1>")]
[TestCase("Content Here")]
[TestCase("This is some content with a <strong>bold</strong> bit in it.")]
public async Task TextCanContainHtmlFormatting(string content)
{
    var context = new TestContext();

    var cut = context.RenderComponent<TextComponent>(parameters =>
    {
        parameters.Add(s => s.TextContent, content);
    });
    
    var textDiv = cut.Find(".text-content");
    Assert.AreEqual(content, textDiv.InnerHtml, "should have the html text content");
}


I would use MarkupMatches(), e.g.:
[Test]
[TestCase("<h1>Content Here</h1>")]
[TestCase("Content Here")]
[TestCase("This is some content with a <strong>bold</strong> bit in it.")]
public async Task TextCanContainHtmlFormatting(string content)
{
    using var context = new TestContext();

    var cut = context.RenderComponent<TextComponent>(parameters =>
    {
        parameters.Add(s => s.TextContent, content);
    });
    
    var textDiv = cut.Find(".text-content");
    testDiv.MarkupMatches($"""
        <div class="text-content">
            {content}
        </div>
        """);
}


Using MArkupMatches is certainly a more elegant assertion and I will make that change. However, it doesn't solve the issue raised in the question. This test still passes if the component is changed to use @TextContent instead of @(new MarkupString(TextContent))  and so it is not able to detect if the html content will be escaped in the rendered output

That seems odd. But you could also simply cut.FindAll(".text-content *") and assert on the number of child elements returned. If html is not escaped, there are more elements returned than if e.g. < is escaped.

An alternative is to assert against cut.Markup. That string contains the raw marked returned from the renderer. There you can look for escaped HTML characters.
